# Comparing records of Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, aggregate

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[np.random.randint(10, 25, size=100), 
                        np.random.randint(10, 25, size=100), 
                        np.random.randint(10, 25, size=100),
                        np.random.randint(10, 25, size=100)]), 
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I need a most efficient way (faster) of doing the following:

```
dd = df.to_dict(orient='index')

for k,v in dd.items():
    v['test'] = len([z['A'] for y,z in dd.items() 
                     if v['A'] > z['A']+3 
                     if v['B'] < z['B']/2])
    
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd,orient='index')
```

This code works but just take ages when dealing with df that have >100k rows.
Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do in words? Looking at the code, you're doing effectively a cartesian comparison, so you're going to be for 100k rows, looping 10,000,000,000 (10 billion) times...

Comment: For each record in this dataframe I want to know how many records meets the mentioned conditions. So for row number 1, how many records in the dataframe have the mentioned conditions, and so on for each records.

Comment: You want to use ```df.apply()```. If you provide your conditions logic in English then it would be easier to help

Comment: Yes please provide an expected output because I "don't understand" the logic behind the result I got after running your code.

Comment: For the first record, if the column 'test' is equal to 10, it means that in the entire dataframe there are 10 records that:
- have their A value + 3 lower than A value of first record 
- AND have their B value /2 greater than B value of first record

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing every item in a column to every other element, this has a big cost - quadratic in the number of rows. We can do this operation in pandas instead of with Python dicts as follows. It's not an algorithmic improvement, so it can still be slow, but it should speed it up by a big constant factor.

As your question is written, handling duplicates is the single biggest improvement you can make if you have thousands of rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[np.random.randint(10, 25, size=size), 
                        np.random.randint(10, 25, size=size), 
                        np.random.randint(10, 25, size=size),
                        np.random.randint(10, 25, size=size)]), 
                  columns=list('ABCD'))


cols = ['A', 'B']

def conditional(row):
    return ((row.A > df['A'] + 3) & (row.B < df['B'] / 2)).sum()

# Use drop duplicates to deduplicate computation - only once for each A, B combination
# Use assign then apply to create a new column with the result of the
# conditional.
# test_counts has columns A, B, test.
test_counts = (
    df[cols].drop_duplicates()
    .assign(test=lambda dcols: dcols.apply(conditional, axis=1))
)

# Use merge and set_index to copy the deduplicated results
# to each occurrence of that A, B combination.
# set_index is for preserving order, remembering it from before the merge.
df2 = (pd.merge(df.reset_index(), test_counts, on=cols)
   .set_index('index').sort_index())
```

Now the code in this particular answer it has a limited number of possible values (as it is in your question), so we don't have quadratic complexity here because of the reduction due to duplicates. But that may change if you have other data.

---

Edited to add

If we look carefully at this condition that we call once per row, we can make it do the same thing with less work.

```py
# before
def conditional(row):
    return ((row.A > df['A'] + 3) & (row.B < df['B'] / 2)).sum()
```

```py
# after
def conditional(row):
    return ((row.A - 3 > df['A']) & (row.B * 2 < df['B'])).sum()
```

We replaced a whole-dataframe-column `+ 3` with just subtracting 3 from the *single element* on the left hand side. The division treated the same way. This saves some significant runtime as well.